# country-language code (ISO 3166) in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, iso, iso-3166, zinc-4

Is there a way to get the country-language code in ISO 3166 (for example: US_en) in actionscript with zinc like I would do in objectiveC:

```
NSString* language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *locale = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];

NSString *updateLocaleLanguage =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@",locale,language];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. You want the Capabilities class:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html